# jQuery DataTables checkboxes extension can not retrive selected data correctly at IE browser

Tags: javascript, checkbox, datatables

I use jQuery datatables checkboxes extension to give my table multi select function. When any row's checkbox is clicked, I retrieve all the selected rows' first cell's data send to server.

The code works in Chrome browser, but does not work in IE browser.

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
    var table = $('#tbl_inv').DataTable({
        "paging": false,
        //"ordering": false,
        "info": false,
        "searching": false,
        'columnDefs': [
            {
                'targets': 0,
                'checkboxes': {
                    'selectRow': true
                }
            }
        ],
        'select': {
            'style': 'multi'
        },
        'order': [[1, 'asc']]
    });

    $('#tbl_inv input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Invoices/Pickup?handler=CalcTotaltoPay',
            data: {
                invIds: $('#tbl_inv').DataTable().column(0).checkboxes.selected().join(),
                clientId:1234
            }
        })
            .done(function (result) {
                freshResult(result);
            });

        // Iterate over all selected checkboxes
        //$.each(table.column(0).checkboxes.selected(), function (index, rowId) {
        //    console.log(index + '---' + rowId)
        //    console.log(table.cell(index, 5).data())
        //});
    });
});
```

When I use IE browser, `.column(0).checkboxes.selected()` returns a list, this list not include current clicked checkbox state change. meaning, when checkbox checked, .column(0).checkboxes.selected() return a list not include current checkbox's data. when checkbox unchecked, .column(0).checkboxes.selected() return a list still include this checkbox's data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the racing condition with jQuery DataTables Checkboxes plug-in. It handles `change` event internally to update the list of selected checkboxes. When you handle `change` event yourself, apparently in IE plug-in is still unaware of the change.

Try using [`columns.checkboxes.selectCallback`](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/reference/options/#columns.checkboxes.selectCallback) option for handling event when state of the checkbox changes.

```
'columnDefs': [
   {
      'targets': 0,
      'checkboxes': {
         'selectRow': true,
         'selectCallback': function(nodes, selected){
            // Handle checkbox state change event
         }
      }
   }
],
```